# SAP Spartacus - How to find wheter the user is logged in or not

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I just want to show one div if the user is logged in already or else I want to show another div with different content. Can anyone guide this to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use the `authService.isUserLoggedIn()` method, that exposes an observable.

You could use it like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn;else #differentContent">
  User is logged in
</div>

<ng-template #differentContent>
  something else
</ng-template>
```

In your component controller you'd addd the `isLoggedIn` property:

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean> = this.authService.isUserLoggedIn();
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

Comment: I followed the same code but it is returning true all the time. Do I need to change anything else to get the correct status?

Comment: I was actually writing it from top of head, so just validated to see if I made a typo or missed something. It seems fine, I just had a small typo: `this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()` (lowercase service ref)